# Using ipython on a different linux account: command gets stuck

Tags: linux, apache-spark, permissions, miniconda, hail

I installed `miniconda3` on one linux account, then I created an environment `py37`, installed all the needed packages and was able to launch `ipython` from the second account and import the package I wanted to import: `hail`. For that I changed all of the permissions in the folder with `miniconda3` to `777`. Somehow, the command when run on the second account gets stuck, but when executed on the initial one where `miniconda3` is installed, it runs successfully:

```
     import hail as hl
---> mt = hl.balding_nichols_model(n_populations=3, n_samples=50, n_variants=100)
     mt.count()
```

The middle command gets stuck. No error, it is just not returning. When I run `hl.balding_nichols_model` on the original account, it is also giving me a warning (but runs successfully, giving the result in `mt.count()`):

> WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable

And the thing is that on another account where the command fails I have Hadoop mounted. So, I have a slight suspicion it is somehow related. I am totally stuck, so would appreciate any suggestions. I need to do it this way - installing `miniconda3` on one account, then accessing it from the other - because on the first account I have terabytes of data free, but on the second - 4Gb and it can't be further expanded unfortunately. With `miniconda3` I would quickly go over the limits.

Additional info regarding the actual software can be found here:

https://hail.is/docs/0.2/getting_started.html#installation

> Update

I installed separately `python37` on the `conda` present on the node and somehow it does not work either, so it is not the problem of permissions, and the issue now is limited to that particular linux account. I installed `spark2.4` but that did not fix the issue. So, the middle command in the python script gets stuck and I do not know even how to get the `log` output, what is going on there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the 'stuck' issue can be found here:

https://discuss.hail.is/t/spark-2-4-4-gets-stuck-in-initialization-phase/1178

I asked it on *Hail* forum and then replied myself there after we fixed the issue. It turned out to be space issue: *hadoop* and *spark* logs should be redirected to different places when you do not have enough of space at the partition you are working on.